# Rails count of 'order by count' returns hash of id=>count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to sort a collection by the count of a `has_many` association:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :laser_sheets, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class LaserSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  ...
end
```

I am able to sort `Jobs` by the number of `LaserSheets` they have:

```
@jobs = Job.left_joins(:laser_sheets)
           .group(:id)
           .order("COUNT(laser_sheets.id) " + sort_direction)
```

However, when I try to get the number of items in `@jobs` I get a Hash of `id => count`:

```
> Job.left_joins(:laser_sheets).group(:id).order('COUNT(laser_sheets.id) DESC').count
 => {100=>5, 88=>5, 66=>5, 77=>5, 47=>5, ...}
```

This only happens when I include the `order` clause in the query. Why does this happen, and how can I get the number of results returned instead of the Hash?

Comment: That happens when you use `count`. Any specific reason why you're invoking that method after all? What's the expected output?

Comment: I display the number of `Jobs` found at the top of the page, so in my view I have "Jobs found: `@jobs.count`". This has always worked until I added the sort by `LaserSheets.count` functionality.

Comment: If so, use `length` instead. `count` and `size` will add a `COUNT(*)` to your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
@jobs = Job.left_joins(:laser_sheets)
           .select("jobs.*", "COUNT(laser_sheets.id) AS laser_sheets_count")
           .group(:id)
           .order(laser_sheets_count: sort_direction)
```

This will give you an additional `laser_sheets_count` attribute on each job record. This lets you display a count without loading the association or creating a N+1 query issue.